# What is the arity of , operator?

Tags: c

Arity is the number of operand(s) an operator can take. For example, `+`, `-`, `*` and `&` are the operators that can be used as both unary (one operand) and binary (two operands). `?:` is the only operator which takes three operands (that's why it is called ternary operator).

But what is the arity of `,` (comma) operator?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator (assuming you're referring strictly to the operator, not as a separator, and explicitly not discussing overloading in C++).

Comment: Re "*that's why it is called ternary operator*" It's actually called the conditional operator. It is merely *a* ternary operator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The comma operator is a binary operator, as indicated by its definition in the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), §6.5.17:

```
Syntax
    1 expression:
            assignment-expression
            expression , assignment-expression
```